# Computer stops detecting Galaxy S7 edge after it enters downloading mode

Tags: android, root

Im currently trying to root an old Samsung Galaxy S7 edge (sm-g935f) and i have gotten to the part where im having it plugged in, in my computer. I type "adb devices" and it gets detected and i get the result "-bunch of letters- Device".

I boot my phone into downloading mode, which is when im supposed to be able to type "fastboot flashing unlocked" and it should start rooting it. But all i get is the . So i check the "adb device" thing again and get a totally blank answer. Not like a command thats loading, it just starts a new line in the terminal.

Please help me, ive been trying to root this god damn phone for hours and im close to throwing it through the wall.

The computer is running linux btw, ive tried on a windows but the same thing happens there :(

Answer (score 0):

It will not show up in adb if you are in "Download mode" because it is not the same think. Adb is Android Debugging Bridge, Download Mode is a "LOKE" protocol for which you need program called "ODIN". This protocol using COM port.